# Modifying a Density Function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, statistics, reference-request

Assuming a real an continuous function $f_1(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ which satisfies Probability Density criteria:

$$ f_1(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \geq 0, \quad \int\limits_0^{+\infty}f_1(x)\mathrm{d}x = 1$$

What happens to this probability density if we censure all values $x < x_0$ to $x_0$ (such as we replace all data less than a Limit of Detection by this threshold).

I though that it might be something like:

$$f_2(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
0,& 0 \leq x < x_0 \\
a\cdot\delta(x-x_0),& x=x_0  \\
f_1(x),& x > x_0& 
\end{matrix} \right.$$

Where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac function and $a$ an arbitraty constant such as $a = \int\limits_0^{x_0}f_1(x)\mathrm{d}x$ in order to keep the area of $f_2$ unitary.

My questions are the following:

- Is this development valid?
- If so, what caution must be taken when dealing with discontinuous probability density?
- Is there a good reference about this kind of problem?

Comment: So $\delta(x_0)$ is what?

Comment: @Stefan Hansen Corrected. $\delta(x-x_0)$ is a Dirac centered on $x_0$.

Comment: But what is $a\delta(x-x_0)$ at $x=x_0$?

Comment: This point represent all my data bellow $x_0$ censored to $x_0$.

Comment: But what is the value of $\delta(x-x_0)$ at $x=x_0$?

Comment: It should be $+\infty$, because $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta(0) = +\infty$.

Comment: You are dealing with a probability measure that has a discrete component. This can be done using measure theory, or it can be done using Riemann-Stieljes integrals. A delta function is just an artificial way of avoiding measure theory, and brings a lot of unnecessary complications. It you understood the Riemann integral, it doesn't take much extra to deal with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, and that leads naturally to measure theory if you decide to go down that road.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes